# How to set field visibillty of all custom fields in salesforce using Metadata API

Tags: custom-field, permissions, permission-sets

I am implementing Salesforce MetadataAPI , i created the custom fields using Metadata API but those fields are not visible , so how to set fieldlevel visibilty to all custom fields using Metadata API

Comment: field visibility is defined on Profile, Permission Sets level. SO you have update it via metadata api accordingly on profile or permission set level

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi Thank You. it works fine but what about if i have multiple users, does it mean i have to update the permission of  custom fields for all users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set these permissions in the [Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) object. They are called `fieldPermissions`, which states if each field is readable, editable, and the name of the field:

```
<fieldPermission>
  <editable>true</editable>
  <readable>true</editable>
  <field>Account.CustomField__c</field>
</fieldPermission>
```

You may want to start by retrieving a Profile to see how this operates. The package.xml might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
  </types>
  <types>
    <members>*</members>
    <members>Account</members>
    <members>Contact</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
  </types>
  <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

Make sure you include all standard objects in the CustomObject element that you wish to retrieve field permissions for.